# Shouldn't CodeIgniter stop using mysql_* functions given that they are deprecated in PHP 5.5?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, deprecated, php-5.5

For example they are used many times in this file: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php

Comment: They do provide you with a whole series of drivers, giving you the choice whether to stick with MySQL or use MySQLi, PDO (or any of the others)

Comment: I make a point of using MySQLi with CodeIgniter and I have never had any issues with it.

Comment: It's called backwards compatibility, and they're serving the masses. `drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php`. Further, if you just go into the `drivers` directory, you will see that there are 12 different supported types within.

Comment: Oh... I wasn't paying attention. Yeah, I'm on mysqli and didn't realize it (in config/database.php):
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';

Comment: The mysql_ functions have been *discouraged* from 4.3 onwards already. The *deprecation* notices are just for the manual and old news eschewers. The *dropping* stage is when it gets relevant again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because that's the file for the MYSQL driver. They also offer a separate MySQLi driver.

Not everyone is going to be switching to PHP 5.5 for a while and there are plenty of legacy applications around. CodeIgniter is intended to remain compatible with older versions of PHP. If you want a more modern framework then there are plenty to choose from - Laravel is a good choice.